# Should I select "Show merge commits in per-file log" in Xcode Source Control?

Tags: xcode, git, gitx, xcode13.3

Is it better to "Show merge commits in per-file log", or not. I'm trying to decide what to choose in Xcode Source Control. I'm not sure what that means. Xcode help doesn't give an answer, and instead gives me a link to search the web. I am the only one using this repository. It is unlikely that this repository will be used by more than one programmer. Is this selection able to be changed later down the road?

Comment: I can't really answer the XCode question, but I'll note that Git doesn't actually *have* a "per file" log. Git stores commits, not files; each commit has a full snapshot of *every* file; and many commits store unchanged files (which they de-duplicate so that they take no *space* but they're logically still in each commit). To see a "per file" log in raw Git, Git has to march through the commits, one pair at a time, and compare: is file F identical in parent and child? If so, don't mention this commit. This breaks down with merge commits because merge commits have *two* parents, not one.

Comment: With the `git log` command, you'd add `-m` to make it report merges in which the file is different in the merge result snapshot,as compared to either or both of the two input parent commit snapshots. Since each invocation of `git log` is something you type in at the terminal, you choose to add `-m`, or not, each time you run it. XCode is presumably emulating this somehow. The details, however, will matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Show merge commits in per-file log` shows ONLY the merge commits when displaying a list of commits to choose from in the **Code Review** feature.

I do my work in a child branch and only push the changes to the main branch when they are ready for deployment, so I’ve found it more useful to have `Show merge commits in per-file log` disabled so I can see the individual commits made locally and the individual commits that have been merged in from the main branch, instead of just merge commits (no local commits and no individual commits that were a part of those merge commits).

NOTE: This setting does not appear to affect the commit list displayed in **Source Control Navigator** which seems to always show local commits plus merge commits (but not individual commits that were part of those merge commits, if that makes sense).

**Example to clarify my terminology:**

Some other developer on the team adds a line of code and commits it in the main branch.  And then modifies some other lines and makes a 2nd commit.  I refer to these as individual commits.

Then I merge those changes into my development branch and for the commit message of the merge I type something like, “Merged recent changes from main into development branch.”.  I refer to this as a merge commit.

Comment: Hi, is there any way to disable showing the "Merge commits" in Source Control Navigator?
I want to see individual commits instead of Merge commits in that window. Is that possible?